# neo4j count all data of one node very slowly

Tags: performance, neo4j

I have a Node named "Event" how I put all events performed by my web portal

Now I have 1 500 000 Events!

So when I count the number of Event, I do this query :

```
MATCH (e:Event) RETURN count(e) AS numberOfEvent
```

But it's extremly slow : 25 000 ms!

The same query, in a classical SGBD like Postgres, is executed in 200 ms!

Is it normal or my query isn't correctly written?

Regards
Olivier

Answer (score 0):

Is that the first time you run the query? Can you run it again?

I think postgres stores the total count, while neo will actually load the data.
So you measure your disk speed for loading the data.

We will work on improving that by using our database statistics internally for this kind of queries.